# Unable to create Azure SQL Data Warehouse, resource does not exist

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Applied for preview access on behalf of my client roughly a month ago. Preview access was approved yesterday. Followed the instructions in the email, namely to create a logical SQL server and reply with the name. Was notified today that the aproval process for the logical SQL server was completed.

Now, when trying to create a new Azure SQL Data Warehouse, it sits there for about an hour before failing on an Update SQL database event. Property mentions statusCode NotFound, and the statusMessage contains code 45181 and message "Resource with the name '' does not exist. To continue, specify a valid resource name."

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for alerting us to this issue. We have investigated the issue and have unblocked the preview access for your subscription. You should be able to proceed and provision an Azure SQL Data Warehouse. You can follow the [Get Starting](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-provision/) guide to provision your first database.